# How to use combineReducer (or any other way) in a typescript project to share data across slices

Tags: typescript, redux-toolkit

I'm confused how to share data across redux toolkit slices in a typescript project. I've read in few answer that it isn't supposed to be possible, and instead combineReducer should be used, or any custom function that has access to the whole state. However, I've not found any example of such use case.

To illustrate my needs, let imagine I want to build a wizard that will flow the user into several steps. At the end, a summary of all inputs and a confirm button will gather all the data and send it to the backend.

This scenario wouldn't actually need to split my redux into multiples slice, but for my understand I will :

- create a slice for each steps
- create a slice for the wizard itself

This has been done in [this sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/redux-hierarchy-yghlsm)

In the wizard slice, I've been able to catch an action using extrareducers :

```js
  extraReducers: (builder) => {
    builder.addCase(generalInfosSlice.actions.submitForm, (state, action) => {
      state.currentStep++;
    });
    builder.addCase(vipInfosSlice.actions.submitForm, (state, action) => {
      state.currentStep++;
    });
  }
```

This allows me to react to the submission of each step, but I have no access to the step state. For example, the 2nd step should only be shown if a checkbox in the 1st step is checked.

Other attempts consists in excluding the wizard logic from the slices in profit of a simple function.

However, because I'm using typescript, I was not able to properly type.

Currently I have :

```js
const rootReducer = combineReducers({
  generalInfos: generalInfosSlice.reducer,
  vipInfos: vipInfosSlice.reducer,
  wizard: wizardSlice.reducer
});

const store = configureStore({
  reducer: rootReducer
});

export type AppDispatch = typeof store.dispatch;
export type AppState = ReturnType<typeof rootReducer>;
```

and my try:

```js
const stepsReducer = combineReducers({
  generalInfos: generalInfosSlice.reducer,
  vipInfos: vipInfosSlice.reducer,
  wizard: wizardSlice.reducer
});

const wizardLogicReducer: Reducer<AppState> = (state, action) => {
  return state;
};

const rootReducer = combineReducers({
  wizardLogic: wizardLogicReducer,
  steps: stepsReducer
});

const store = configureStore({
  reducer: rootReducer
});

export type AppDispatch = typeof store.dispatch;
export type AppState = ReturnType<typeof rootReducer>;
```

It does not compiles because of circular type inference.

Exact error is `'wizardLogicReducer' is referenced directly or indirectly in its own type annotation.ts(2502)`

What is the proper way to handle that ?

PS: if it matters, my actual business requirement is to build several wizards that may share some steps. To keep it maintainable, every steps are living in dedicated packages, and the wizards in different packages too. That means every steps have actually no knowledge of the wizard itself, only dedicated slice. I've been able to actually configure the slice in different packages, but I didn't found a way to manage the wizard state itself.

Comment: Since the wizard would cut across slices then the wizard should probably not have its own slice but rather read the data it needs when it needs them

Comment: Not sure to get how I should do that. Eventually I'll need to dispatch an action to send the gathered data to the backend. How to access this data? You mean not from any redux related code but from the Wizard component itself?

Comment: I don't know the context you are going to use this on but I don't generally agree with the idea that each component should have its own slice in the state because it would lead to situations such as yours or in situations where things in the state are duplicated in multiple slices and actions affect multiple parts of the state at the same time so I would just get the data the wizard component requires from the entire state

Comment: My steps are very complex, and go beyond simple forms. And my steps may be reused by multiples different wizard, each living in separate apps. That's why I have to make the steps agnotics to the big pictures. Wizards however, have steps well knowns. What I was hoping, and the redux doc seems to tell it's supposed to be possible, is to have some kinda tree of reducers. But I don't get how to build the top level reducers (I guess slice cannot be used for that). Especially regarding the typings